# function to create buttons receiving "text" and "onclick function" by parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do what I said in the title.
I tried this:

```
function createButton(func, text){
    var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var btTxt = document.createTextNode(text);
    btTxt.style.color = '#006633';
    btTxt.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    butt.onclick = func;
    butt.appendChild(btTxt);
    butt.style.margin = '5px';
    document.body.appendChild(butt);
}
```

And this:

```
createButton(doSomething, click to do something);
```

But it doesn't work :/

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set styles of the button, not TextNode object:

```js
function createButton(func, text) {
    var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var btTxt = document.createTextNode(text);
    butt.style.color = '#006633';
    butt.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    butt.onclick = func;
    butt.appendChild(btTxt);
    butt.style.margin = '5px';
    document.body.appendChild(butt);
}

createButton(doSomething, 'click to do something');

function doSomething() { alert('Hello'); }
```